# Does virtual memory always provide a larger address space to a process?

Tags: memory, memory-management

From what I understand, a process is allocated real memory space, i.e., RAM. This is fixed so if the process needs more memory, it gets it from virtual memory.

So what the virtual memory does is just swaps pages into/out of the processes memory space as required, however, the processes REAL memory space remains constant.

My question is, is it possible for virtual memory to physically change the real memory space of the process in order to give it more memory?

Comment: As far I remember is the main reason for virtual memory that traditional the excitable code begins always at the same address in the memory. That would mean that you could only run one program, the virtual memory maps the memory so that the programmes won't overlap and override their executable code.

Comment: @rekire So does this mean that when a process is being run, the disk is reading from the virtual memory because its ordered?

Comment: No that is something else the hard drive is only used if the ram is full. That is of cause bad for performance of the "stashed" program, because on resume it must go the slow (delayed) way over the hard drive.

Comment: No, your premise is not accurate. Processes ask for virtual address space (not "RAM") either directly or indirectly (directly by calling functions like `malloc`, `VirtualAlloc`, `sbrk`, etc. or indirectly by mapping a file) and the OS uses physical RAM to fill the address space on an as-needed basis.

Comment: And a process' virtual address space is not always necessarily "larger" than anything else (including physical memory). For example, it's possible to have a machine with 256GB of RAM running a 64-bit OS hosting 32-bit processes that have only 4GB of address space.

Comment: @AndrewMedico When do processes indirectly ask for memory? I am familiar with directly asking for memory but I didn't realise that processes ask for more memory by themselves. Can you give me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the risk of oversimplification, a process is allocated a page table (for simplicity, assuming a single level page page). The page table has a number of entries. each entry represent at a potential page in memory. The maximum size of the page table is limited by the address space of the processor. However, the operating system may restrict the page page size smaller than this.

(Assuming each executable starts a new process) The application loader will set up the address space to an initial state that includes all the static data, executable code, pre-allocated modifiable data, and an initial state.

There is no physical memory at this point.

As the program start up, it will reference pages in virtual memory that have no physical memory (page fault). The operating system will then assign physical memory pages to the virtual pages. At startup there will be many page faults.

As the application runs it can allocate more virtual memory up to the limits of the page table size.

As the application runs, the operating system can remap physical memory to virtual memory. The same virtual address can have multiple physical addresses while the program runs.

So this is an incorrect assumption.

> From what I understand, a process is allocated real memory space, i.e., RAM. This is fixed so if the process needs more memory, it gets it from virtual memory.

This is not correct:

> So what the virtual memory does is just swaps pages into/out of the processes memory space as required, however, the processes REAL memory space remains constant.

Yes to this:

> My question is, is it possible for virtual memory to physically change the real memory space of the process in order to give it more memory?